# Spring Boot full REST CRUD example

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Does anyone have a full spring boot REST CRUD example? The spring.io site just has a RequestMapping for GET. I'm able to get POST and DELETE working but not PUT.

I suspect it's how I'm trying to get the params where the disconnect is, but I have not seen an example where someone is performing an update.

I'm currently using the SO iPhone app so I can't paste my current code. Any working examples would be great!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you can see I have implemented two way to update. 
The first one will receive a json, and the second one will receive the cusotmerId in the URL and json also.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Customer greetings(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Eddu");
        customer.setLastname("Melendez");
        return customer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Customer> list() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void add(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void update(@RequestBody Customer customer) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateById(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Customer customer) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete() {

    }

    class Customer implements Serializable {

        private String name;

        private String lastname;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setLastname(String lastname) {
            this.lastname = lastname;
        }

        public String getLastname() {
            return lastname;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Eddú. I think the method list should not carry a PathVariable because it should return all customers in the system right? See http://www.slideshare.net/stormpath/rest-jsonapis as reference.

Comment: The second PUT was what I was looking for. It made me realize that I was not sending the id in the body of the request, just in the URI. This now works for me.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative update returns ResponseEntity object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/fruits")
public class FruitController {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FruitController.class);

    @Autowired
    private FruitService fruitService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Fruit>> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "offset", defaultValue = "0") int index,
            @RequestParam(value = "numberOfRecord", defaultValue = "10") int numberOfRecord) {
        LOG.info("Getting all fruits with index: {}, and count: {}", index, numberOfRecord);
        List<Fruit> fruits = fruitService.getAll(index, numberOfRecord);

        if (fruits == null || fruits.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<List<Fruit>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<Fruit>>(fruits, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Fruit> get(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        LOG.info("Getting fruit with id: {}", id);
        Fruit fruit = fruitService.findById(id);

        if (fruit == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Fruit>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Fruit>(fruit, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody Fruit fruit, UriComponentsBuilder ucBuilder) {
        LOG.info("Creating fruit: {}", fruit);

        if (fruitService.exists(fruit)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        }

        fruitService.create(fruit);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(ucBuilder.path("/fruit/{id}").buildAndExpand(fruit.getId()).toUri());
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Fruit> update(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody Fruit fruit) {
        LOG.info("Updating fruit: {}", fruit);
        Fruit currentFruit = fruitService.findById(id);

        if (currentFruit == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Fruit>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        currentFruit.setId(fruit.getId());
        currentFruit.setName(fruit.getName());

        fruitService.update(fruit);
        return new ResponseEntity<Fruit>(currentFruit, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
        LOG.info("Deleting fruit with id: {}", id);
        Fruit fruit = fruitService.findById(id);

        if (fruit == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        fruitService.delete(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

From [Spring MVC RESTFul Web Service CRUD Example](http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-mvc-tutorial/spring-mvc-restful-web-service-crud-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a set of tutorials on Spring Boot CRUD Operations. Following are the content of tutorials:

1. How to create Spring Boot Project using Spring Tool Suite
2. How to implement GET & POST method in spring boot restful web service
3. How to implement PUT & DELETE method in spring boot restful web service
4. Integrate PostgreSQL database using spring boot JPA with spring boot restful web service
5. Use of CURL commands

**Youtube Tutorials:**

1. [Spring Boot Restful Web Service Tutorial | Tutorial 1 -
   Introduction](https://youtu.be/zM5JEDpoUr0)
2. [Spring Boot Restful Web Services CRUD Example GET & POST | Tutorial - 2](https://youtu.be/CiNemYAFARQ)
3. [Spring boot CRUD Operations example PUT & DELETE  | Tutorial - 3](https://youtu.be/7YA6rSlM16k)
4. [Spring Boot JPA | In 5 Simple Steps Integrate PostgreSQL Database | Tuorial - 4](https://youtu.be/kighQ0NWJlg)

Visit [Blog](http://sjtechsagar.blogspot.in/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can get my full RESTful server and client app using SpringBoot at [Spring RESTFul Examples at github](https://github.com/newfound-systems/example-spring-RESTful-with-spring-boot)

Comment: Did you remove your repository? Can you update it here or remove your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.cats.hcm.bussinessObjects.Address;
import com.cats.hcm.bussinessObjects.Employee;
import com.cats.hcm.bussinessObjects.EmployeeBO;
import com.cats.hcm.bussinessObjects.MaritalStatus;
import com.cats.hcm.bussinessObjects.State;
import com.cats.hcm.repository.EmployeeRepositoryImpl;
import com.cats.hcm.repository.MaritalStatusRepositoryImpl;
import com.cats.hcm.repository.Repository;
import com.cats.hcm.repository.StateRepositoryImpl;
import com.cats.hcm.services.EmployeeServiceImpl;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/newemployee")
public class NewEmployeeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Repository.class);

    @Autowired
    Repository repository;

    @Autowired
    StateRepositoryImpl stateRepositoryImpl;

    @Autowired
    MaritalStatusRepositoryImpl maritalStatusRepositoryImpl;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepositoryImpl employeeRepositoryImpl;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeServiceImpl employeeServiceImpl;


    @RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeBO employeeBO, BindingResult bindingResult) throws SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {

        logger.info("==========="+new Gson().toJson(employeeBO));
        logger.info("========Employee ID========"+employeeBO.getEmployeeId());
        repository.addToDataBase(employeeBO);   
        String msg="Success";
        return msg;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String updateEmployee(@RequestBody EmployeeBO employeeBO, BindingResult bindingResult) throws SecurityException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {

        logger.info("==========="+new Gson().toJson(employeeBO));
        logger.info("========Employee ID========"+employeeBO.getEmployeeId());

        //Deleting Existing Employee
        Boolean isDeleted = employeeServiceImpl.deleteEmployeeDetails(employeeBO.getEmployeeId());
        if(isDeleted) {
            repository.addToDataBase(employeeBO);
        }
        String msg="Success";
        return msg;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/employeeData")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployeeDataTablePage() {
        logger.info("======getEmployeeDataTablePage======");
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepositoryImpl.readAll(); 
        logger.info("========EmployeeList========="+new Gson().toJson(employeeList));

        return employeeList;        
    }


    @RequestMapping("/modifyPage")
    public @ResponseBody List<Employee> getEmployeeModifyPage(@RequestParam("employeeId") String employeeId) {
        logger.info("========getEmployeeModifyPage====EmployeeID:===="+employeeId);
        //List<State> stateList = stateRepositoryImpl.readAll();
        //List<MaritalStatus> maritalStatusList = maritalStatusRepositoryImpl.readAll();

        //model.addAttribute("stateList", stateList);
        //model.addAttribute("maritalStatusList", maritalStatusList);

        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepositoryImpl.readAll();
        logger.info("========employeeList:===="+employeeList);


        EmployeeBO employeeBO = employeeServiceImpl.getEmployeeBO(employeeId);
        logger.info("========getEmployeeModifyPage====EmployeeBO:===="+employeeBO);


        return employeeList;

        //return new ModelAndView("apps-mod-employee", "employee", employeeBO);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public @ResponseBody String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("employeeId") String employeeId) {
        logger.info("========deleteEmployee===EmployeeID:===="+employeeId);
        //employeeRepositoryImpl.delete(employeeServiceImpl.getEmployeeBO(employeeId));
        Boolean isDeleted = employeeServiceImpl.deleteEmployeeDetails(employeeId);
        if(isDeleted) {
            logger.info("========Employee Record Deleted===EmployeeID:===="+employeeId);
        }
        return "redirect:/employee/employeeDataTable";
    }
    /*@RequestMapping("/employeeDataByEmpId")
     public String getEmployeeAddPage(Map<String, Object> model) { 
    public ModelAndView getEmployeeDataByEmpId(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("======getEmployeeDataByEmpId======");

        String EmployeeID=request.getParameter("empId");

        Employee employee = employeeRepositoryImpl.read(EmployeeID);

        logger.info("========Employee========="+new Gson().toJson(employee));

        model.addAttribute(new EmployeeBO());
        model.addAttribute("employeeByEmpId", employee);
        //return "apps-add-employee";
        //return new ModelAndView("apps-add-employee");
        return new ModelAndView("apps-employee", "employee", new EmployeeBO());
    }*/
}
```